# Is there a fast way to build numpy/pandas diagonal to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Ok,i have an array of systems = np.array([ 1,  3,  1,  7,  1, 15,  1,  7,  1,  3, 1], dtype=np.int8)

I want to know if there is a faster way to build the following dataframe or numpy matrix rather than the formula what im using now:

```
systems = np.array([ 1,  3,  1,  7,  1, 15,  1,  7,  1,  3, 1], dtype=np.int8)            
                                                                                                                                    
def buildsystem(system):  
  firstrow = [0]   
  sysbuild = pd.DataFrame()  
  for y in range(len(system)):   
    firstrow.append(system[y] ^ firstrow[y])   
  sysbuild[0] = firstrow  
  for y in range(1,len(system)+1):  
    sysbuild[y] = system[y-1] ^ sysbuild[y-1]  
  return sysbuild 

h= buildsystem(systems)

In [145]: h                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[145]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0    0   1   2   3   4   5  10  11  12  13  14  15
1    1   0   3   2   5   4  11  10  13  12  15  14
2    2   3   0   1   6   7   8   9  14  15  12  13
3    3   2   1   0   7   6   9   8  15  14  13  12
4    4   5   6   7   0   1  14  15   8   9  10  11
5    5   4   7   6   1   0  15  14   9   8  11  10
6   10  11   8   9  14  15   0   1   6   7   4   5
7   11  10   9   8  15  14   1   0   7   6   5   4
8   12  13  14  15   8   9   6   7   0   1   2   3
9   13  12  15  14   9   8   7   6   1   0   3   2
10  14  15  12  13  10  11   4   5   2   3   0   1
11  15  14  13  12  11  10   5   4   3   2   1   0

np.diagonal(h, 1)

In [144]: np.diagonal(h, 1)                                                                                                                                                       
Out[144]: array([ 1,  3,  1,  7,  1, 15,  1,  7,  1,  3,  1])
```

you will notice that systems is the exact same as np.diagonal

Is there faster way to accomplish this. I will be working with int sizes of up to 64 and wanted a faster way way to look these up. Any help will be appreciated. You will notice build systems is not using numpy or pandas functions

Thank you

Comment: I have never heard of an "array of systems". I am curious to know what that is and what the matrix represents. Do you have any reference I can read ?

Comment: Oh, this is just an xor tree. From these numbers ( i forgot two so its not a complete xor tree, but as you can see if you xor a row and column, you get a xor answer, and that xor tree can be built from the array. I’m working on doing a little more advanced things with it but was looking for a better way to do it and got an amazing answer! I hope this helps. At least sort of because i need to edit it with a full tree

Comment: But they do XOR correctly in this case if you take the first row and first column and xor by those the point they meet is the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a loop, you can build your output with the [`accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) version of [`bitwise_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html) and broadcasting:

```
firstrow = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(np.r_[0, systems])

out = firstrow[:,None]^firstrow

print(out)
```

*NB. for a DataFrame: `out = pd.DataFrame(firstrow[:,None]^firstrow )`.*

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 1  0  3  2  5  4 11 10 13 12 15 14]
 [ 2  3  0  1  6  7  8  9 14 15 12 13]
 [ 3  2  1  0  7  6  9  8 15 14 13 12]
 [ 4  5  6  7  0  1 14 15  8  9 10 11]
 [ 5  4  7  6  1  0 15 14  9  8 11 10]
 [10 11  8  9 14 15  0  1  6  7  4  5]
 [11 10  9  8 15 14  1  0  7  6  5  4]
 [12 13 14 15  8  9  6  7  0  1  2  3]
 [13 12 15 14  9  8  7  6  1  0  3  2]
 [14 15 12 13 10 11  4  5  2  3  0  1]
 [15 14 13 12 11 10  5  4  3  2  1  0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
systems = np.array([ 1,  3,  1,  7,  1, 15,  1,  7,  1,  3, 1], dtype=np.int8)            
                                                                                                                                    
def buildsystem(system):  
  firstrow = [0]   
  for y in range(len(system)):
    firstrow.append(system[y] ^ firstrow[y])
  sysbuild = [firstrow]
  for y in range(1,len(system)+1):
    sysbuild.append(system[y-1] ^ sysbuild[y-1])
  return np.array(sysbuild) #or pd.DataFrame
   
h = buildsystem(systems)
```

As a general rule appending/inserting into numpy arrays or pandas dataframes is quite costly. It is almost always better to do as much as possible on simpler data structures such as lists, and only doing a conversion at the end. Even the conversion itself is quite fast.

I only reworded your function to avoid inserting into a dataframe. I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible to rewrite your function completely with some sort of rolling/sliding trick to take care of the recursive, but nothing comes to mind right now

Comment: In numpy, this kind of "recusrive" behavior is often performed with `accumulate` (see my answer)